# defining a new backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I was trying to extend backbone collections, the first way i was doing new in the declaration and in the second I declared first and then I created a new instance. Is doing the first wrong, what is the difference?

```
var AppointmentList = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Appointment
});
```

and

```
var AppointmentList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Appointment
});

var aptlist = new AppointmentList();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one will break

```
var Appointment = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "time": "0000",
        "note": "This is an appointment"
    }
});


var AppointmentList = new Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Appointment

});

var aptlist = new AppointmentList();
```

In in Backbone.js we have

```
  var extend = function(protoProps, staticProps) {

    var parent = this;
    var child;


    if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, 'constructor')) {
      child = protoProps.constructor;
    } else {
      child = function(){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); };
    }

    _.extend(child, parent, staticProps);


    var Surrogate = function(){ this.constructor = child; };

    Surrogate.prototype = parent.prototype;

    child.prototype = new Surrogate;


    if (protoProps) _.extend(child.prototype, protoProps);


    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;

    return child;

  };
```

If you instantiate Backbone.Collection.extend with the `new` operator, then the `var parent = this` will refer to the extend object, but if you don't use `new` then `var parent = this` will refer to `Backbone.Collection` and since you can only call `.apply` on functions, the code will break here:

```
child = function(){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); };
```

`parent` will be an object. `Backbone.Collection` is a function